# list the subfolders in a folder - Matlab (only subfolders, not files)

Tags: list, matlab, directory, dir

I need to list the subfolders inside a folder using Matlab.  If I use

```
nameFolds = dir(pathFolder),
```

I get `.` and `..` + the subfolder names.  I then have to run `nameFolds(1) = []` twice. Is there a better way to get the subFolder names using Matlab?  Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `isdir` field of `dir` output to separate subdirectories and files:

```
d = dir(pathFolder);
isub = [d(:).isdir]; %# returns logical vector
nameFolds = {d(isub).name}';
```

You can then remove `.` and `..`

```
nameFolds(ismember(nameFolds,{'.','..'})) = [];
```

You shouldn't do `nameFolds(1:2) = []`, since `dir` output from root directory does not contain those dot-folders. At least on Windows.

Comment: If you want to include all hidden subdirectories (e.g. if you work with `git`), you may use `startsWith(nameFolds, '.')` instead of `ismember(nameFolds,{'.','..'})`.

Answer (score 8):

This is much slicker and all one line:

```
dirs = regexp(genpath(parentdir),['[^;]*'],'match');
```

Explained:
`genpath()` is a command which spits out all subfolders of the `parentdir` in a single line of text, separated by semicolons. The regular expression function `regexp()` searches for patterns in that string and returns the option: 'matches' to the pattern. In this case the pattern is any character not a semicolon = `[^;], repeated one or more times in a row = *. So this will search the string and group all the characters that are not semicolons into separate outputs - in this case all the subfolder directories.

Comment: This command lists the main folder as well as the subfolders -- it's not what the asker wanted.

Comment: This answer helped me in listing all sub directories quickly. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution! But you need to remember that `genpath` function designed to generate search path, so it skips some specific folders. See the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html).

Comment: Also, you need to use pathsep instead of hardcoding semicolon, since the path separator differs on unix than windows.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet just returns the name of sub-folders.

```
% `rootDir` is given
dirs = dir(rootDir);
% remove `.` and `..`
dirs(1:2) = [];
% select just directories not files
dirs = dirs([obj.dirs.isdir]);
% select name of directories
dirs = {dirs.name};
```

Comment: For a one-liner after first line: `dirs = {dirs([dirs.isdir] & cellfun(@(d)~all(d=='.'), {dirs.name})).name}`.

Answer (score 0):

And to effectively reuse the first solution provided in different scenario's I made a function out of it:

```
function [ dirList ] = get_directory_names( dir_name )

    %get_directory_names; this function outputs a cell with directory names (as
    %strings), given a certain dir name (string)
    %from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748976/list-the-subfolders-
    %in-a-folder-matlab-only-subfolders-not-files

    dd = dir(dir_name);
    isub = [dd(:).isdir]; %# returns logical vector
    dirList = {dd(isub).name}';
    dirList(ismember(dirList,{'.','..'})) = [];

end
```